# Reinstall of Windows Bootloader not working

Tags: bootloader

It first started when I deleted my partition that had Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Little did I realize at the time that it would destroy all the resources of Grub on it, and subsequently prevent me booting into my hibernated windows 7. So I made a 12.10 Ubuntu live USB and reinstalled windows bootloader. When I rebooted it gave me a bootloader error saying I that it could not find the resources to boot from. So I went back to my live USB and installed boot-repair and tried to repair the mbr. It didn't work though. Here is the URL the boot-repair gave me if I was in trouble:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1328309

EDIT: I have a laptop that has no cd drive so I cannot use the windows install disk. Also I don't own the disk :P

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Guide to remove Grub and Reinstall windows boot loader

Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer.

Press a key when you are prompted.

Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.

Click Repair your computer.

Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.

In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.

Type following commands in cmd

```
bootrec/fixmbr
bootrec/fixboot
```

Comment: I don't have a boot disk and my comp is a laptop with no cd drive :P thx for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with **Boot-Repair**, you need a working internet connection.

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Follow the on screen prompts and reboot.

For more info, have a look at the [community page.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) Good luck! Let us know if it works.

Comment: sorry, didn't see you tried it.

Comment: I really have no idea why it doesn't work. Thx anyway.